# How to combine comparisons of the same variable in if statements

Tags: c, conditional-statements, coding-efficiency

```
if (i != 0 && i != 15 && i != 20)
{
    ...
}
```

For the above code snippet, how can I combine all the conditions so I won't have to use multiple comparison operators?

Comment: For however many conditions :>

Comment: Sometimes a bit of context is important. How many conditions are you expecting to put there, and what problem is being solved? There might be a more practical way to express it.

Comment: Put all the values to check against in an array. Use a loop to check each value one by one. Set a flag to indicate state, and break early if `i == value`.

Comment: For straight-up equality testing with integers, you could jam them all into a `switch` statement, and for `!=` put the code block into the `default` section. Whether that's "nice", or "readable" depends very much on the task at hand. It's more stuff to type, so that's probably not what you're asking.

Comment: C doesn't really have a shortcut for this.

Comment: `if (!inarray(i, (int[]){0, 15, 20}, 3)) { /* ... */ }` ... the `inarray()` function implementation is left as an exercise

Comment: More context is needed. On a far out leg, maybe you can combine many of your conditions mathmatically: like `if (i%5 != 0 || i>20 || i=5 || i=10 || i<0)` and then sort out the special cases like in this case 5 and 10. For the given example this makes of course no sense, but if you have many unwanted values or more helpful patterns....

Comment: With [GNU extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html), you can get close to syntax you might find in other languages by using macros, e.g., [`CMP(i, !=, 0, 15, 20)`](https://godbolt.org/z/hTMToe5Ma), but this is not ideal for two reasons: portability, and because what you've written is perfectly understandable for small sets of comparisons. Really, any more than that starts to beg the question as to why there are so many hard-coded values (magic numbers at that), and if there is a better way to tackle the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In other languages, you might use something like:

```
if (!(i in (0, 15,20)))
{
    ...
}
```

But as far as I know, this does not work in C.

So there's no way out of this.

However, I would advise you to use the following formatting:

```
if (i != 0  && // meaning of  0 value
    i != 15 && // meaning of 15 value
    i != 20)   // meaning of 20 value
{
    ...
}
```

As you see, putting every single condition on a separate line increases readability and gives you the opportunity to add comments for that one condition. The usage of such comments is seen as a burden by starting programmers, but once you have experienced the burden of needing to re-think a piece of code, multiple months after having developed it, you'll understand the usage of such comments :-)

Comment: "But as far as I know, this does not work in C." Or rather in C you'll have to implement the function yourself. After which your code probably runs much faster than "fancy language x"... and maybe contains a few more bugs as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 3 checks to perform, the chained `&&` in your original code is probably the most readable and shouldn't be changed. Just keep De Morgan's Laws in mind when negating boolean expressions - getting those wrong is a common bug.

You could use a loop, but that's probably only sensible if you have a whole lot of checks to carry out than just 3:

```c
const int conditions[] = {0, 15, 20};
bool ok= true;

for(size_t i=0; i<sizeof conditions/sizeof *conditions; i++)
{
  if(n==conditions[i])
  {
    ok = false;
    break;
  }
}

if(ok)
{
  ...
}
```

For values less than 256 you could also perhaps use `memchr`, though that's also more obscure than what you already have:

```
#include <string.h>

const unsigned char conditions[] = {0, 15, 20};
if(memchr(conditions, n, sizeof conditions) == NULL)
{
  // n does not equal any of the conditions
}
```

Comment: And for _a lot_ of conditions, `bsearch`.